# ORA-00907: missing right patenthesis

Tags: sql

I just can't see what needs to be changed in this code:

```
create table tblGirlScout (
    GirlScout_ID varchar(10,0) not null,
    GirlScoutFirstName varchar(25) not null,
    GirlScoutLastName varchar(25),
    GirlScoutAddress varchar(30),
    GirlScoutCity varchar(20),
    GirlScoutState char(2),
    GirlScoutPostalCode varchar(9),
    Constraint tblGirlScout_PK Primary Key(GirlScout_ID)
);
```

Comment: `varchar(10, 0)` does not make sense as a type.  Oracle is expecting a `)` at the first comma.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you wanted to set GirlScout_ID column as a number, not a varchar. This is what causes the problem. Here is a fix

```
create table tblGirlScout (
    GirlScout_ID number(10,0) not null,
    GirlScoutFirstName varchar(25) not null,
    GirlScoutLastName varchar(25),
    GirlScoutAddress varchar(30),
    GirlScoutCity varchar(20),
    GirlScoutState char(2),
    GirlScoutPostalCode varchar(9),
    Constraint tblGirlScout_PK Primary Key(GirlScout_ID)
);
```